# how can calulate size on based on dynamic generated div element id

Tags: jquery

I want to know that i have dynamic generated div element with unique id i want to add textbox init from dropdown changes .. so how can i calulate that how many input element are already present here... plz tell me code on size()..

```
 $(Idvalue).bind('change',function () {

       var index1 = $this((".child input")).size();
            var requested = $((this[this.selectedIndex]).val(), 5);

            if (requested > index1) {
                for (i = index1; i < requested; i++) {
                    var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: '' });
                    $("#chileage_" + forage).append($ctrl);
                }
            }
            else if (requested < index1) {
                var x = requested - 1;
                $("#chileage_ input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
            }
        });
```

.child is my class ...bt i want to calulate size on id value plzzz help me out..

Comment: If you want to know how many elements match a selector, use `$(selector).length`. For example: `$(".child input").length`. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find the width/height of an element in jQuery would just be:

```
var height = $('#element_id').height(),
    width = $('#element_id').width();
```

If you want to dig a little deeper, you could also query the `padding`, `margin`, `border-width`, etc.